# FFmpeg function avdevice_list_devices causes C++ Runtime error

Tags: c#, windows, pointers, ffmpeg, unsafe

I use Windows, C#, FFmpeg.AutoGen.
I want to get list of devices.

```
public static class Helpers
{

    private static unsafe AVDeviceInfoList** _devicesList;

    public static unsafe void GetMediaSourceNames()
    {

        ffmpeg.avdevice_register_all();

        AVFormatContext* context = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();

        ffmpeg.avdevice_list_devices(context, _devicesList);

    }

}
```

Function avdevice_list_devices() causes error:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library.
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Another reason for the error:

```
Assertion s->oformat || s->iformat failed at src/libavdevice/avdevice.c:192
```

If we look at the context in debugging, we will see that `context.oformat` and `context.iformat` are equal to zero.

**UPDATE 2**

If set some non-zero value, then the error will disappear.
Like this:

```
AVInputFormat avformat = new AVInputFormat();

(*context).iformat = &avformat;
```

But can't get list of devices.
Now the code looks like this. The last line throws an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". But in debugging can see the value of `nb_devices` is ten (in fact, there are no devices at all).

```
public static class Helpers
{

    private static unsafe AVDeviceInfoList* _devicesList;


    public static unsafe void GetMediaSourcesNames()
    {

        ffmpeg.avdevice_register_all();

        AVFormatContext* context = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();


        AVInputFormat avformat = new AVInputFormat();

        (*context).iformat = &avformat;


        fixed (AVDeviceInfoList** devicesListPointer = &_devicesList)
        {
            ffmpeg.avdevice_list_devices(context, devicesListPointer);
        }


        int devicesQuantity = (*_devicesList).nb_devices;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is found. Need to use newer version of FFmpeg and different method (avdevice_list_input_sources).
This code works in the following conditions: Windows 7, .NETFramework 4.5.2, FFmpeg.AutoGen 5.1.2.3, FFmpeg libraries 5.1.2 from gyan.dev.

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static unsafe void Main()
    {

        DynamicallyLoadedBindings.Initialize();

        ffmpeg.avdevice_register_all();

        AVInputFormat* iformat = ffmpeg.av_find_input_format("dshow");

        AVDeviceInfoList* deviceListPointer = null;

        int result = ffmpeg.avdevice_list_input_sources(iformat, null, null, &deviceListPointer);

        if (result < 0)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {result} / 0x{result:X8} / {GetErrorDescription(result)}");

            if (result == -5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No devices");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            return;

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{result} devices");
        }

        AVDeviceInfoList deviceList = *deviceListPointer;

        for (int i = 0; i < deviceList.nb_devices; i++)
        {

            AVDeviceInfo deviceInfo = *deviceList.devices[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < deviceInfo.nb_media_types; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((deviceInfo.media_types)[j]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(BytePtrToStringUtf8(deviceInfo.device_name));
            Console.WriteLine(BytePtrToStringUtf8(deviceInfo.device_description));

        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static unsafe string GetErrorDescription(int errorNumber)
    {

        byte[] chars = new byte[1000];

        fixed (byte* charsPointer = &chars[0])
        {
            ffmpeg.av_strerror(errorNumber, charsPointer, (ulong)chars.Length);

            return BytePtrToStringUtf8(charsPointer);
        }

    }

    private static unsafe string BytePtrToStringUtf8(byte* bytePtr)
    {

        if (bytePtr == null) return null;
        if (*bytePtr == 0) return string.Empty;

        List<byte> byteBuffer = new List<byte>();

        while (true)
        {
            byte currentByte = *bytePtr;

            if (currentByte == 0)
                break;

            byteBuffer.Add(currentByte);

            bytePtr++;
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteBuffer.ToArray());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointers usage is wrong.

Replace `private static unsafe AVDeviceInfoList** _devicesList;` with:

```
private static unsafe AVDeviceInfoList* _devicesList; //Pointer to AVDeviceInfoList structure
```

Replace `ffmpeg.avdevice_list_devices(context, _devicesList);` with:

```
ffmpeg.avdevice_list_devices(context, &_devicesList); //Pass the memory address of _devicesList.
```

---

The fact that `avdevice_list_devices` argument is defined as pointer to  pointer, doesn't mean we can declare a variable with `**` and pass it as an argument.

The C syntax of `**` (pointer to pointer) is very confusing.
In our case it means that we should pass the address of a pointer, and the functions returns a new pointer.
The returned pointer points a list of devices.

The function dynamically allocates the memory for storing the list, fills the list, and returns a pointer to the list.

For releasing the allocated memory, execute:

```
avdevice_free_list_devices(&_devicesList)
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem with the pointer to the list is solved.
Just one clarification:
`fixed (AVDeviceInfoList** devicesListPointer = &_devicesList)
{
    ffmpeg.avdevice_list_devices(context, devicesListPointer);
}`
Otherwise, the compiler throws an error.
But now a new error. Updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, I answered the question as it was C, without knowing the correct C# context, and without testing. Listing all devices seems more complicated than I thought. I found a C example [here](https://qtox.github.io/doxygen/cameradevice_8cpp_source.html). It's too complicated for me to implement it in C#.

Comment: No problem! No need to apologize! My correction is intended for future readers of this thread.